# CoreMidi parse MIDI Song Position

Tags: position, midi, coremidi

I'm trying to parse received midi value and show it in the following format:

bars:beats:divisions:ticks

I have following code:

```
unsigned short CombineBytes(unsigned char First, unsigned char Second) 
{ 
    unsigned short _14bit;

    _14bit = (unsigned short)Second; 
    _14bit<<=7; 
    _14bit|=(unsigned short)First; 
    return(_14bit); 
}

-(void) midiSource:(PGMidiSource *)input midiReceived:(const MIDIPacketList *)packetList{

    const MIDIPacket *packet = &packetList->packet[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < packetList->numPackets; ++i)
    {

        Byte statusByte = packet->data[0];
        Byte status = statusByte >= 0xf0 ? statusByte : statusByte >> 4 << 4;

        if (status == 0xF2){

            NSLog(@"%i", CombineBytes(packet->data[1], packet->data[2]));
        }
    }
}
```

Basically when Logic Pro, or Ableton Live sending song position signal, I'm receiving value like 404, 405, etc...

For example: 404= 026:02:01
Where 026 = bars, 02= beats, 01 - divisions. This part is clear for me...

But how to get tickets? That is the problem, it's either something I do not understand. Or for that should be different midi signal. But I looked to the Midi Monitor and I didn't saw something other.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MIDI standard 1 beat = 6 clocks. The latter ones are sent via the timing clock message (0xF8).